# Show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi (x) dx= 0$

Tags: integration, manifolds, global-analysis

Let $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}\mathbb{(R)}$ . I need to show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi (x) dx = 0$ iff there exists a function  $\psi \in C_{c}^{\infty}\mathbb{(R)}$ such that $\phi(x) = \psi ' (x)$.

I have absolutely no clue how to begin. Any help with this is appreciated!

Comment: What is  $C_c^\infty$ the [Riemann Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)?

Comment: Is it right that $\;\int_{\Bbb R}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\;$ , an improper integral?

Comment: I was thinking it was the extended complex plane. In that case if $\phi(x) = \phi'(x)$ then the integral only depends on the end points, which are the same on this space

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: @Dark_Knight But then $\;x=\left((\frac{x^2}2\right)'\;$ in $\;C_c^\infty(\Bbb R)\;$ , yet the integral $\;\int_{\Bbb R}x\,dx\;$ doesn't even converge...Maybe some data is missing, like Principal Values and stuff?

Comment: @DonAntonio You make a valid point. But the previous questions that I solved (involving such integrals) worked out to be fine. This is a Lebesgue integration. No such extra data is given.

Comment: @Dark_Knight Even if this is Lebesgue Integral we have a problem here as improper Lebesgue integrals are defined by means of improper *Riemann* integrals, and this last doesn't exist in this case.

Comment: Usually $C_c^\infty$ stands for infinitely differentiable compactly supported functions which will everything well defined

Comment: @clark Nothing is mentioned. But I can work with a compact support over $\mathbb{R}$, say $[-M,M]$.

Comment: If nothing is mentioned then I suppose they follow the standard use for $C_c^\infty$, then we can define $\psi(x) = \int _{-\infty}^x \phi(u) du$ and since $ \int _{-\infty}^\infty \phi(u) du=0$ we see that $\psi(x) \in C_c^\infty$

Comment: @clark Thank you. I will try the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Say $\operatorname{supp}\psi \subseteq [-M, M]$. Then, it follows
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} \phi = \int_{\mathbb R} \psi' = \int_{-M}^M \psi' = \psi(M) - \psi(-M). $$

On other hand, assume $\operatorname{supp} \phi \subseteq [-M, M]$. Then,
$$ \psi(x) = \int_{-M}^x \phi $$
has compact support if and only if
$$ \psi(M) = \int_{\mathbb R} \phi = 0. $$